# Key binding for window/app in python Gtk+ 3 without menu items, UI manager, etc

Tags: python, gtk, keyboard-shortcuts, gtk3, gobject-introspection

I'm trying to use GTK3 and Cairo from Python for a minimal plotting application where the on-screen display of Cairo's output is for user convenience.

The typical usage is that I run a command, a plot pops up on screen and is also written to file, and I want to be able to dismiss the window as quickly as possible, ideally just a "q" keypress but also the common Ctrl-W and Ctrl-Q in addition to the default Alt-F4 (does anyone really use that regularly?!?).

I also want as little UI clutter in the window as possible: ideally just the standard window surround, no menus, toolbars, etc.

So... how can I bind my "q", "Ctrl-Q", etc. keybindings to `Gtk.main_quit` without having to a) create a cluttersome drop-down menu bar and b) go though the heavyweight `Gtk.UIManager` focused on by the Python Gtk+ 3 documentation here: http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/menus.html . I hope this is possible, and doesn't require a lot of code (at least not as much as to set up all the menus!), but I can't find an example anywhere online: maybe I'm just searching for the wrong terms, being a GTK newbie.

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any documentation on making such a minimal accelerator setup, and the code to configure accelerator keys seems to differ a great deal between GTK2 and 3... thanks for helping.

Comment: Keep in mind PyGTK (Gtk+ 2.x only) is something completely different from the `gi.repository` introspection bindings which are used (as you do) when doing Gtk+ 3 programs in python.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I wasn't sure if they were different versions of the same project or entirely separate. Sounds more like the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connect a signal to your main frame `Win.connect('key-press-event', self.on_key_function)` and in on_key_function (self, widget, event) check the value of event.keyval. For ESC is 65307 if you like hardcoded. Also, for key combinations, event.state report shift, alt(meta), and so on: `if Gdk.ModifierType.CONTROL_MASK & event.state:do_something if ctrl is pressed`
You could have separate stataments for left-ctrl, right-alt; be sure not to try to capture predefined key combinations, thay may be consumed by window manager.
A IDE with a good introspection will help you a lot, just write Gdk (previously imported) and autocompletion will popup a lot of functions/clases, most of them with a self-explanatory name.

Comment: Excellent, that's refreshingly compact compared to the tutorials which were all aimed at bigger things!

Comment: Bad recommendation. `event.keyval` is layout-dependent, such hotkeys won't work in non-Latin keyboard layouts.

Comment: I don't have time to check, but it was the „all-in-one” solution - the code was the same in windows/linux. And the layout was not identical (but yes, both latin). Feel free to update, I'm busy with house paintings

Answer (score 0):

Don't use key-press-event and keyval, it won't work for users with non-Latin keyboard layouts. GTK+ does a great job internally to match keyvals to hardware keys, this functionality is exposed via accelerators (often shortened as  `accel` in the API) and bindings.

Comment: Maybe could show an example of how you would do that?

Comment: @Thayne, sorry, not in Python, but for accelerators there's [an example in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19793067/3075942), hope it helps.